# Microsoft Connection dialog missiong radio button on windows server

Tags: wpf, winforms

I am using microsoft data connection dialog (Winform) for my wpf project, it works fine on windows 7, but on windows server, the radio button is missing, could anyone help?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across a similar problem ([How come the width of a checkbox in my WPF-application differ between XP and Win7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972086/how-come-the-width-of-a-checkbox-in-my-wpf-application-differ-between-xp-and-win)) for XP. This was resolved using the Windows Vista/7 Aero theme.

I do not have an environment where I can try this but if you want to give it a shot here is how you do it:
http://arbel.net/2006/11/03/forcing-wpf-to-use-a-specific-windows-theme/

Comment: But Microsoft data connection dialog is a winform window, will themes affect winform controls?